# SMTP BLOCK GMAIL ACCOUNT(mail goto spam and bounce mail)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, aws-sdk

I have applied smtp method for sending mail through api and frontend. i configure gmail for smtp and used AWS server but after 10 to 15 mail my gmail account block and not able to send mail.
because of "ohio" region AWS not provide smtp.

Comment: Did you try sending through another region, say us-east-1?

Comment: Well, SES works irrespectove of region as they're public endpoint so you can use SES but since gmail blocked you, gmail for smtp should allow to send 2000 emails per day, what error do you get when you send emails ? I believe you're using this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: I receive two type of error in my gmail account. 
1- Your message to abc@xyz.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.    2 - You have reached a limit for sending mail. Your message was not sent.